# Permitir valores negativos y positivos numeros decimales

Tags: javascript, regex

Hola tengo esta función que da formato a un numero con separador de miles y decimales pero quiero adicionar que acepte números negativos ¿Qué tendría que aumentar? Gracias.

```
function  FormatNumber(event) {
    var dec = $(this).data('decimal');
    var aux = "([0-9])([0-9]{" + dec + "})$";
    var expReg = new RegExp(aux);
    $(event.target).val(function (index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(expReg, '$1.$2').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo `[+-]?`a tu expresion regular, en tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function FormatNumber(event) {
    var dec = $(this).data('decimal');
    var aux = "([+-]?[0-9])([0-9]{" + dec + "})$";
    var expReg = new RegExp(aux);
    $(event.target).val(function (index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(expReg, '$1.$2').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos